# Extract image src using JSoup

Tags: jsoup

I am trying to extract all the image url's from this webpage using jsoup? Can anyone offer help on how to do it? All the tags are formatted like this, but I only need the src image, not the ajaxsrc:

```
<IMG ajaxsrc="/pics32/160/MP/MPYXBXTSYVKAKJQ.20110918032436.jpg" src="http://image.cdnllnwnl.xosnetwork.com/pics32/160/MP/MPYXBXTSYVKAKJQ.20110918032436.jpg">
```

Here is the link:
http://www.ncataggies.com/PhotoAlbum.dbml?DB_OEM_ID=24500&PALBID=417884

Is this the format?

```
        Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(articleLink).timeout(10000).get(); 
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        return null;
    }
    Element content = doc.getElementById("div.thumb-image preview");
    Elements links = content.getElementsByAttribute("IMG");
    for (Element link : links) {
      String source = link.attr("src");
      Elements imageLinks = link.getElementsByAttribute(source);
      for(Element imageLink: imageLinks){
          //imageLink = picture link?
      }

}
```

That doesn't seem to be it. I have print statements in my code, and they aren't getting hit.

Answer (score 16):

You should be able to do something like this to get all img tags:

```
for (Element e : doc.select("img")) {
    System.out.println(e.attr("src"));
}
```

This should select all img tags and then grab the src attribute and print to the console.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you already have the Element according to this IMG, try this:

String source = img.attr("src");

This attr method is inherited from Node class

HTH

Comment: well, not exactly. I just know the format of the img tag, but its nested in a div tag. So I dont know how to extract it.

Comment: Well, in that case, put the div on a Element object, then call getElementsByAttribute("src") that should return an array of those IMG elements.

Comment: can you give me an example, I'm trying to visualize what you are saying

Comment: Take a look here: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation. Where you see getElementById you should provide your outer div ID. Then, having the element, generate a collection using getElementsByAttribute. Each element of this collection would be an IMG, then you could use the attr method

Comment: this may not be possible. The div id is "thumb-2", then the next one is "thumb-3" and so on. They all have the same class ID, can I use that?

Answer (score 0):

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(" http://www.ncataggies.com/PhotoAlbum.dbml?DB_OEM_ID=24500&PALBID=417884").get();

        Elements elements =document.getElementsByTag("IMG");
        for(int i=0;i<elements.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Sources of "+ i +":"+elements.get(i).attr("src"));
        }
```